# Nightmares replacing text string with img src

Tags: php

I've had a nightmare of a time trying to get this HTML/PHP code to work for about a week, so I thought I'd try my luck here.

I've been trying to overhaul a link to use an image instead of a text string, but I get punctuation errors (namely, an "unexpected comma") every time, even though the code I adapted from another part of the page works fine there.

Here's the original code:

```
            echo '
    <div id="modbuttons_top" class="modbuttons clearfix margintop">
        <div class="floatleft middletext">', $txt['pages'], ': ', $context['page_index'], !empty($modSettings['topbottomEnable']) ? $context['menu_separator'] . '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#bot"><strong>' . $txt['go_down'] . '</strong></a>' : '', '</div>
        ', template_button_strip($normal_buttons, 'bottom'), '
    </div>';
```

The attempted (broken) revision:

```
                                                echo '
    <div id="modbuttons_top" class="modbuttons clearfix margintop">
        <div class="floatleft middletext">', $txt['pages'], ': ', $context['page_index'], !empty($modSettings['topbottomEnable']) ? $context['menu_separator'] . '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#bot"><img src="', $settings['lang_images_url'], '/new.gif" alt="', $txt['new'], '" /></a>' : '', '</div>
        ', template_button_strip($normal_buttons, 'bottom'), '
    </div>';
```

If anyone can figure out how to work out this mess, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Use the ternary before `echo` it will be much easier to read. You are concatenating not echoing so do `$context['menu_separator'] . '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#bot"><img src="'. $settings['lang_images_url']. '/new.gif" alt="'. $txt['new']. '" /></a>'`.

Comment: @chris85: It works beautifully! If we were in the same place I'd buy you a coffee. Thanks so much.